# Kmean algorithm on high resolution images

Tags: python, image-processing, k-means, nearest-neighbor

I have an image with 22500x55000x3 shape and I want to apply kmean algorithm on this image. Unfortunatelly it takes so much time even if I run the algorithm in a server. What can be done for this situation ?

Here the code I used.

```
import os
os.environ["OPENCV_IO_MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS"] = pow(2,40).__str__()
import cv2
import numpy
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread("images/2021/true_color_08.jpg")
mask = cv2.imread("images/2021/09/all_08.jpg")

image = cv2.bitwise_and(image,mask, dst = image)

pixel_values = image.reshape((-1, 3))
# convert to float
pixel_values = numpy.float32(pixel_values)

criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 0.2)

k = 4
_, labels, (centers) = cv2.kmeans(pixel_values, k, None, criteria, 10, cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)

# convert back to 8 bit values
centers = numpy.uint8(centers)
centers[0] = [255,255,255]
centers[1] = [255,0,0]
centers[2] = [0,255,0]
centers[3] = [0,0,255]

# flatten the labels array
labels = labels.flatten()

segmented_image = centers[labels]

# reshape back to the original image dimension
segmented_image = segmented_image.reshape(image.shape)
# show the image
plt.imshow(segmented_image)
plt.show()
```

Comment: reduce dimensionality before you reduce dimensionality.  you probably aren't looking for an _exact_ solution anyway because kmeans is probably probabilistic. **downscale** the data you use for finding cluster centroids. once you have the cluster centroids, you can *assign* each pixel from the full-res image.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz you mean as first downscale and apply the algorithm the upscale your image to original, right ? I tried it but I missed a lot of detail. My image is high resolution but it has small objects. It is a satellite image and you can assume I try to segment each 10x10 area in this image.

Comment: *no*, do not upscale. if you thought I meant that, you need to review. you need to split the "kmeans" call into finding centroids, and then assigning values to centroids. the first part is the expensive step.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I did it as well, I splitted image into pieces and applied kmeans to them then tried to join the resulst but it does not produce correct results. Here the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73801737/applying-k-mean-algorithm-to-image-patches) related it

Comment: I did not say to split the image.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz sorry for misunderstanding, can you explain what you mean with details ?